# Subsetting a dataframe in R by retaining first occurrences of unique elements from all columns

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

`df` is a test dataframe which has 5 rows and 6 columns and it is a subset of a much larger dataframe (dimensions: 1000000 X 30).

```
df <- data.frame(
 Hits = c("Hit1", "Hit2", "Hit3", "Hit4", "Hit5"),
 category1 = c("a", "", "b", "a", ""),
 category2 = c("c", "", "", "d", "c"),
 category3 = c("", "", "e", "f", "f"),
 category4 = c("", "", "", "", ""),
 category5 = c("i", "", "i", "j", ""))
```

`df` looks like this

[image]

For each column from `category1` to `category5` I need to retain only the first occurrences of all the unique elements. e.g. For `category1`, the unique elements are `a` and `b` and their first occurrences are in rows 1 and 3 respectively. So rows 1 and 3 should be retained, and so on. The output should look something like this

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `lapply` and `duplicated` you could first replace duplicates per column by `""`, then filter for rows containing at least one non `""` string:

```r
df[-1] <- lapply(df[-1], function(x) {
    x[duplicated(x)] <- ""
    x
})
df <- df[rowSums(!df[-1] == "") > 0, ]
df
#>   Hits category1 category2 category3 category4 category5
#> 1 Hit1         a         c                             i
#> 3 Hit3         b                   e                    
#> 4 Hit4                   d         f                   j
```

Answer (score 2):

I was challenged to find a `tidyverse` solution and ended up with this, not to recommend as solution but as a learning effect:

The basic idea was to bring the data in long format remove the duplicates and bring back to wide format, but this "simple" idea turned out to be quite complicated as you can see here:

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
  pivot_longer(
    everything()
  ) %>% 
  mutate(value = na_if(value, "")) %>% 
  unique() %>%
  group_by(id = cumsum(name=="Hits")) %>% 
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>% 
  pivot_wider() %>% 
  fill(everything(), .direction = "updown") %>% 
  filter(if_any(category1:category5, ~ !is.na(.))) %>% 
  slice(1) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  select(-c(id, row)) %>% 
  mutate(across(everything(), ~replace_na(.,"")))
```

```
  Hits  category1 category2 category3 category4 category5
  <chr> <chr>     <chr>     <chr>     <chr>     <chr>    
1 Hit1  "a"       "c"       ""        ""        "i"      
2 Hit3  "b"       ""        "e"       ""        ""       
3 Hit4  ""        "d"       "f"       ""        "j"
```

Answer (score 2):

Another possible solution, based on `dplyr` and `purrr::map_dfc`:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(
  Hits = c("Hit1", "Hit2", "Hit3", "Hit4", "Hit5"),
  category1 = c("a", "", "b", "a", ""),
  category2 = c("c", "", "", "d", "c"),
  category3 = c("", "", "e", "f", "f"),
  category4 = c("", "", "", "", ""),
  category5 = c("i", "", "i", "j", ""))

df %>% 
  map_dfc(~ if_else(duplicated(.x), "", .x)) %>% 
  filter(rowSums(. == "") != 5)

#> # A tibble: 3 × 6
#>   Hits  category1 category2 category3 category4 category5
#>   <chr> <chr>     <chr>     <chr>     <chr>     <chr>    
#> 1 Hit1  "a"       "c"       ""        ""        "i"      
#> 2 Hit3  "b"       ""        "e"       ""        ""       
#> 3 Hit4  ""        "d"       "f"       ""        "j"
```

Comment: Better `tidyverse`! :-)

Comment: My first solution was similar to yours, @TarJae! But then I saw I was going to post a solution already posted by you and, therefore, I had to think about a different solution... :-)

Answer (score 1):

A data.table version, following @PaulS's tidyverse approach; Might help speed wise with 1,000,000 rows, etc.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)

df = cbind(df[,1], df[,-1][, lapply(.SD, \(x) fifelse(duplicated(x),"",x))])
df[rowSums(df[,-1]=="")<5]
```

Output

```
   Hits category1 category2 category3 category4 category5
1: Hit1         a         c                             i
2: Hit3         b                   e                    
3: Hit4                   d         f                   j
```